# Compound Nodes in Cytoscape JS

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

What do [Compound Nodes](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#selectors/compound-nodes) mean in Cytoscape JS?

Answer (score 7):

A compound node is a node that has one or more other nodes within it.  It's similar to embedded divs in HTML.

Comment: except I think unlike nested divs, nested (compound) nodes don't have relative positioning (layout) — correct?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Cytoscape doc](https://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/compound-nodes):

A compound node contains a number of child nodes, similar to how a HTML DOM element can contain a number of child elements.

compound parent node does not have independent dimensions (position and size), as those values are automatically inferred by the positions and dimensions of the descendant nodes.

You can check this [demo](https://js.cytoscape.org/demos/compound-nodes/) and [code](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/tree/master/documentation/demos/compound-nodes)